# How showing with matplotlib 2 lines after setting a new index

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a graphic where i can follow the points of a certain team in a season: With pd.loc i have all my data, that's working.

First, i have tried showing bars. That's ok. But when a ask a line, he showed me 1.

[image: 1 line]

```
pd.set_index("thuis",inplace = True)
result = pd.loc[["Anderlecht","RC Genk"],['datum','pthuis_totaal']].sort_values(by=['datum'])
result.head().plot(kind='line', x='datum', y='pthuis_totaal', color=['red','green'])
```

I hope for a little help of you. Thx